# Lightweight aggregates and repositories

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Let's assume that we have two simple domain objects : 
Topic (entity) -> Messages (value object)

These two domain objects could be included into one aggregate according to DDD principles.

But in some cases we need to retrieve topics without messages (if want just show a list of topics) and sometimes we need to retrieve topics with messages.

What is the best way to design that simple case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to separate domain logic from data needed for presentation. Something like Command-query separation (CQS) or command-query responsibility segregation (CQRS). For example, if someone adds a new message to topic, you create an appropriate command and handle it as a part of your domain logic. And if you need to display some data in user interface, you select only data that you really need through DTO (data transfer object). This solution avoids of unnessesary data retrieving and helps to keep simplicity. You retrieve only data you really need.

If this solution causes a lot of changes in your project, you can create an additional method in repository that returns a lightweight version of your aggregate (with default stub for Messages collection). But this solution has one drawback - you will need to keep in mind that this method returns incomplete data.

Comment: The second variant with 'lightweight' aggregate is clear for me, but I do not like approaches like 'keep something in mind' cause they tend to be error prone ones. I am looking into CQS/CQRS right now. It looks okay except the point that date should be duplicated. If a topic and message are quite big (contains a lot of fields) then I have to include these fields in my DTO. To put it simply then I will end up maintaining one more additional data container...